# nested foreach as LINQ with chained linked List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List within a list. I only need the one value from the list and can do obtain my result with a nested foreach but I want to use a LINQ query of some sort.

my code:

```
var myCity = from c in CountryLists
           select (from city in c.stateList
                   where city.name == passedInValue
                   select city.name).FirstorDefault();
```

This returns myCity as a list of some sort with all values as null *EXCEPT* for where the match was found.

i don't want to have to walk through the city list to find the name. How can I have only one value in myCity; either null or the desired name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `SelectMany` to flatten the list, then `FirstOrDefault` to filter:

```
CountryList.SelectMany(c => c.stateList).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == passedInValue);
```

Note that because `FirstOrDefault` can take a predicate, you don't actually need the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 4):

How about using SelectMany:

```
var city = CountryLists
           .SelectMany(x => x.stateList)
           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == passedInValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` as other have pointed out (and I prefer that solution myself), however if you'd like the query syntax, you can use multiple `from` clauses (check the [**MSDN documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx) for more examples):

```
var city = (from c in CountryLists
            from city in c.stateList
            where city.name == passedInValue
            select city.name).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is equivalent to the `SelectMany` method solution, it uses it under the covers anyway.