# how to use Except or Remove method based on nested list condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex object with multiple levels of nesting.  An `Order` contains several `Orderline`s internally and each `Orderline` has `Product` list. I need to delete/remove the `Orderline`s that have products whose UseByDate is older than today.

I've tried

```
orders.Orderlines.RemoveAll(x => x.products.FindAll(z => z.UseByDate > DateTime.Now);
```

My classes:

```
class Order
{
    public int Orderid { get; set; }
    public string customerName { get; set; }

    public List<Orderline> Orderlines { get; set; }
}

public class Orderline
{
    public int orderid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int orderlineid { get; set; }
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int orderlineid { get; set; }
    public DateTime UseByDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. I have no idea what you mean by "nested object list" nor do I know what your objects look like, but for some reason I assume the answer is to use LINQ's `SelectMany` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912901/nested-foreach-as-linq-with-chained-linked-list).

Comment: Are you saying that A has a list of B, and B has a list of C, and you want to remove items from the list of C that B has? If so, it's not really a LINQ question.

Comment: have updated the question with code. basically need to remove all products that have an older use by date from the orders - orderline - products list.

Comment: can you show us what the structure for these objects are?

Comment: thanks for editing your question with more information. Please provide more information on the following. The intended use: why are you trying to remove products with dates greater than today? Are you trying to remove them permanently from the orders list of orderlines or are you trying to return a result that has only orders in the past? If you are just trying to remove orders that are in the future, why don't you just do a check when adding a product to orderlines so that if its in the future it can't be added? like i said please add more info, how ur using ur classes doesnt make sense to me

Comment: I am calling multiple api's and then combining to get the orders object. so i don't have control while adding items. I just need to filter the list. now i need to remove the products that have an older than today, use by date

Comment: i still dont see why you can't filter the data before its added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RemoveAll removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate. i.e. The bit in the brackets needs to return a boolean.

```
orders.Orderlines.RemoveAll(o => o.products.Any(p => p.UseByDate > DateTime.Now))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var order in orders.Orderlines) {
    bool isValid = true;
    foreach(var product in order.Products) {
       if (DateTime.Compare(product.UseByDate, DateTime.Now) > 0) {
            isValid = false;
       }
    }
    if (isValid = false) {
        orders.OrderLines.Remove(order);
    }
 }
```

i think something like this should accomplish that (old fashion way instead of using linq).

When using linq you should return a list that has all the objects (orderlines) that have invalid orderlines. then have a foreach that removes them. To my knowledge it is best practice to separate the selecting/finding and the removing/action elements (but i could be wrong :D )